# Allow user to add text to drop down list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Within Google Sheets, I would like to show my users a drop-down list from a list on a different tab.  I want the users to be able to enter their own text if what they are looking for isn't in the list.  How can I do this without having an invalid message appear the users or the red triangle in the upper right-hand corner?

Could I use autocomplete somehow to use the list on the previous sheet?  This would mimic how the drop down is working.

Answer (score 0):

if you do it like this, then you just tell them to add stuff in G column under your selection. eg. everything in G column will appear as a selection in the drop-down menu.

[image: 0]

---

if you worry not to delete your stuff you can give them E column and put this into your G column:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(E:E, "where E is not null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

but if their skill is equal to yours then just teach them to add what they need by themselves directly:

[image: 0]